# Ember Data creates duplicate record on model save() | ember-cli v3.19

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, single-page-application, ember-cli

Ember duplicates models on save.
I have two models

```
**bill**

export default class BillModel extends Model {
    @attr("string", { defaultValue: "", uppercase: true })
    vehicleNumber;

    @attr("string", { defaultValue: "" })
    customerName;

    @attr("number", { defaultValue: "" })
    customerMobileNumber;

    @attr("date")
    createdOn;

    @hasMany("bill-item")
    billItems;

    @attr("number", { defaultValue: 0 })
    total;

    @computed(
        "billItems.@each.cost"
    )
    get computedTotal() {
        let total = 0;
        this.billItems.forEach((item) => {
            if (item.cost)
                total += parseFloat(item.cost);
        });
        return parseFloat(total);
    }
}


**bill-item**

export default class BillItemModel extends Model {
    @attr("string", { defaultValue: "" })
    itemName;

    @attr("number", { defaultValue: null })
    cost;
}
```

Then I create a new record of the "bill" model and create a "bill-item" record and add that in the billItems property of the bill model.

```
let bill = this.store.createRecord("bill");
bill.billItems.addObject(this.store.createRecord("bill-item"));
```

then when I use the save() the "bill" model, I now have two records in the billItems property.
One with id returned from the server response and one with
But I should have only one.
Below is the server response.

```
{
  "vehicleNumber": "1231",
  "customerName": "123",
  "customerMobileNumber": 1231232312,
  "createdOn": null,
  "total": 23123,
  "billItems": [
    {
      "itemName": "1231",
      "cost": 23123,
      "id": "9510"
    }
  ],
  "id": 467
}
```

Why does the ember store now have 2 records of "bill-item" model when I tried to save only one?
The adapter used for the models are RESTAdapter and serializer is JSONSerializer.

[Ember inspector attachment for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkkjo.png)

Comment: I think you have two records because you `createRecord` twice. I don’t think you need the second one at all.

Comment: No. I've created a bill-item record only once using createdRecord(). If I shouldn't be using the second createRecord, then how am I supposed to add bill-item records to the bill model?

Comment: @r4M you can still use my solution

Comment: @MichałHabigier Yes I can use yours but its more like a hack. I'm looking to find out the exact reason for this behaviour and to see if this a bug or if I'm doing anything that is not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Save the `billItem` first.

After

```
let bill = this.store.createRecord("bill");
bill.billItems.addObject(this.store.createRecord("bill-item"));
```

`bill` contains a `billItem` with only default attributes, and thus undefined `id`. When the API response from `bill.save()` comes back, ember-data accepts the response as the new state of the record it just tried to save, updating everything that is different to the model in store (i.e. your back-end could modify other attributes and they would be updated).

Apparently, your back end created a `billItem` record, too, upon receiving a `bill` that includes an embedded `billItem` without an id. However, since ember-data never explicitly saved this `billItem`, the embedded `billItem` is treated as a different record apparently also associated with the `bill` and thus added to its relation. (I do not have a good intuitive explanation why the association with the old, id-less one is still there - I guess it's because ember-data still treats it as an unsaved `billItem` record (green in the inspector) and still remembers its (inverse) relation with the original `bill`.)

Another fix might be not to serialize embedded records but only ids and retrieve the records separately, but if each `billItem` belongs to exactly one bill this may not be what you want.

Comment: This works if we are saving each object separately. However, if we try to include relationships in a single request, it ends with duplicate models. @Michał Habiger's solution is better for such case.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem. Since I didn't have enough time for having considerations about of it I decided to use simple workaround. Just in case of succesful save, you can invoke

```
foo(){
  this.store.peekAll('bill-item')
      .filterBy('isNew', true)
      .forEach(item => this.store.deleteRecord(item));
}
```

And then, all records without id should have been removed from the store.
However, I'd gladly hear some explanations of that issue from more experienced ember developers.